# Mongoose validation error when i try to save array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

When I try to create a new Case in my node js app i get validation errors for each field:

```
due_date_of_payment
due_amount
due_amount_currency
```

Mongoose thinks they are empty for a reason

Here is my case model schema

```
module.exports = new Schema({

    ...
    invoices: [
      {
          due_date_of_payment: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
          },
          due_amount: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          },
          due_amount_currency: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            enum: ['EUR'],
          },
      }
    ],
   ...
```

However if i send invoices as object with keys due_date_of_payment, due_amount and due_amount_currency

and change invoices in the model to be object and not array, everything is OK and the new document is returned to the frontend

Comment: what is the request that you're sending & what is the error that you're getting ?

Comment: @whoami i'm seind a nested object exactly like the schema
`
{
...,
invoices: [{
   ...fields
}],
...
}
`
and i get errors only for due_date_of_payment, due_amount and due_amount_currency ( the errors are that they are required like im not passing fields in the object inside the invoices array )